# A word for: "previous generations that no longer exist"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

I am searching for the most concise and well-sounding way to say

> *my foremost inspiration is the photos of previous (deceased) generations*.

I cannot find a suitable word or succinct expression to describe something **belonging to previous generations that have died out**. I also don't want to sound negative by implying the death of previous people.

Moreover, is there a better way of saying: *it inspires me*? Should I say: *I am inspired by*?

Comment: Your last sentence is another question. And the phrase in the title borders on tautology...

Comment: 1) ask only one question 2) please indicate what research you have done 3) this question appears to me to be writing advice ("the most concise and well-sounding way to say..."), which is offtopic here. You can ask on the Writing stack exchange

Comment: I think it is a good question. To appease the naysayers, (it's much easier for some users to find minor faults than merits), include the definitions, and synonyms  of [**previous**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/previous) and [**generation**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/generation)

Comment: *dead ancestors*

Answer (score 4):

I would use “bygone” in that context—“bygone generations/times/eras”. Other good alternatives include “past generations” (or “generations past”), “my/our forebears”, or “those that have gone before me/us”.

These don’t all *require* that the generations in question be deceased, but they can strongly imply it based on context.

Answer (score 1):

**Antecedents** might work. Strictly speaking, it refers to your own family's ancestors, but it is commonly used to refer to the culture and cohort of your ancestors as well.

> Why launch ourselves on this most ambitious of inquiries, if we can loiter instead in the theories of our antecedents?

https://books.google.com/books?id=0Zm7NvtkN5UC&lpg=PA59&dq=%22our%20antecedents%22&pg=PA59#v=onepage&q=%22our%20antecedents%22&f=false

> Our antecedents moved their agriculture into the great river valleys
>   [...]

https://books.google.com/books?id=btzraYnY9E4C&lpg=PA7&dq=%22our%20antecedents%22&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q=%22our%20antecedents%22&f=false

Comment: Or decedents...

Answer (score 0):

Ancestral

from https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/ancestral :

*adj.
of or belonging to or inherited from an ancestor*

*Ancestral things have been around so long that they once belonged to your ancestors, the family members who lived before your grandparents were born.*

The implication of "ancestral" is that the people have since died, but without sounding negative.

e.g. "The ancestral pictures on the walls inspire my resolve."

Answer (score 0):

Forebear ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forebear))

> ancestor, forefather; also :  precursor —usually used in plural His forebears fought in the American Civil War.